# "This syntax requires an imported helper but module 'tslib' cannot be found" with ES2015 modules

Tags: typescript

I have demo project I'm about to compile to ES5 with ES2015 modules enabled and `tslib` used for external TS helpers:

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^1.9.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.1.3"
  }
}
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strict": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

*src/index.ts*

```
function a(target: any) {
    return target;
}

@a
export class Foo {}
```

This results in an error:

> src/index.ts:5:1 - error TS2354: This syntax requires an imported helper but module 'tslib' cannot be found.

While `lib/index.js` is correctly compiled:

```
import * as tslib_1 from "tslib";
function a(target) {
    return target;
}
var Foo = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Foo() {
    }
    Foo = tslib_1.__decorate([
        a
    ], Foo);
    return Foo;
}());
export { Foo };
```

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 300):

The problem for me was that the editor was using a different TypeScript version than the project.

To fix that:

1. Open Command Palette (Cmd+Shift+P on Mac. Focused file must be .ts or .tsx otherwise it won't show the option to change version)
2. Select "TypeScript: Select TypeScript Version..."
3. It shows VSCode's TS version and Workspace's (project) one, pick that one (Note: this assumes [you have `npm install`ed the packages in the workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53818521/1175496))
   [image: select typescript version]
   Or click on the version number at the bottom bar if it shows in there:

[image]

Comment: After updating to Ng12, with tslib already installed and getting `This syntax requires an imported helper but module 'tslib' cannot be found.` error, this easy solution was all I needed. PS, answer is a little ambiguous so to clarify you must pick: `Workspace's (project)`

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer because the OP does not mention they are using VSCode.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I changed from the built-in version 4.7.3 to the local node_modules same 4.7.3, and the errors went away ...

Comment: Same here, this fixed my issue. VS Code were using 4.7.3 so I switched to Workspaces's 6.4.6 version and it fixed.

Comment: The worked for me, but I had to additionally use the "TypeScript: Reload project" command.

Answer (score 249):

Try something like:

```
npm install tslib --save-dev
```

Or, to fix noob mistake (which I just made):

```
npm i
```

I mean, personally before signing off on Friday,
I did a `git clean -fxd`, but no `npm i`, so all the npm packages were missing. Doh!

Comment: I'll never know why this isn't included in one of the _many_ angular dependencies :(

Comment: "tslib is not a dependency of angular itself. But rather a dependency of the TypeScript compiler when you enable TypeScript importHelpers.

Any library that is compiled using importHelpers should always have a direct dependency on tslib and not rely on other libraries to install it."

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13886#issuecomment-471927518

Comment: git clean -fxd command removed all useful files too. (.env and shared folders)

Comment: @Aravin that's why you don't run any command you see on the internet

Answer (score 71):

Add below lines to `tsconfig.json`

```
"compilerOptions": {
    //...rest parameters

    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "tslib" : ["path/to/node_modules/tslib/tslib.d.ts"]
    },
```

Comment: This seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 34):

In my case removing or setting the `importHelpers` compiler option to `false` resolved the issue.

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "importHelpers": false, // Or remove this
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Since ```true``` is the default value, does it have any impacts on the application side when setting it to ```false``` ?

Answer (score 24):

In my case, tslib was already installed and i was seeing this error only for 1 component while everything else was working fine - build and functionality.
I just restarted my vscode and it vanished.
So, try that if the error is still there after you have done things which others have suggested.

Comment: It really helps sometimes to restart IDE or devserver in case there are obscure TS errors that aren't reproducible and shouldn't be there.

Comment: Yup, got the same problem, restarting VSCode fixed it for me. :)

Answer (score 21):

Just updated tslib to latest version, and problem had been fixed. I had installed `1.9.3`, and updated to `1.10.0`.

Answer (score 10):

As [the reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) states, module resolution is set to Node mode only for `"modules": "commonjs"`, and is set to classic mode for `"modules": "es2015"`:

> There are two possible module resolution strategies: Node and Classic. You can use the --moduleResolution flag to specify the module resolution strategy. If not specified, the default is Classic for --module AMD | System | ES2015 or Node otherwise

Since classic mode is unaware of `node_modules`, the compiler cannot resolve `tslib` module.

`moduleResolution` should be set explicitly for ES2015 modules:

```
...
"module": "es2015",
"moduleResolution": "node",
...
```

Comment: I also had to set "target" as well.

Answer (score 9):

My error appeared to be sporadic but likely caused by editing a file in the "node_modules" folder.

I deleted

- "node_modules" folder
- "package-lock.json" file

Ran ... "npm install"

It is now working.

NOTE: I tried running "npm install' prior to deleting the files and that did not solve the issue.

Comment: That's correct, it may be necessary to delete node_modules, `npm install` is not enough to forcibly reinstall. A specific damaged package can be reinstalled with `npm install packagename` but this doesn't work for all packages and won't fix all dependency problems. Deleting package-lock.json without good reasons is strongly discouraged and may bring new problems, unless you know that the problem propagated there.

Answer (score 6):

update the dependencies and devDependencies of tslib in package.json

```
{
   dependencies:{
     "tslib": "1.10.0",
   },
   devDependencies:{
     "tslib": "1.10.0",
   }
}
```

Comment: Imo adding only to dependencies should be enough, they're installed in development mode too.

Comment: @Zmey it only works in devDependencies for me.

Answer (score 5):

You have to remove from
 `"compilerOptions": { "importHelpers": true, }` on tsconfig.json

Answer (score 4):

**npm install**

If you see this error the first time you open a new project or repository, you probably simply haven't installed the app's required modules yet.

In the directory of the app, run:

`npm install`

Answer (score 3):

In my case the error `Cannot find module 'tslib'` was caused by special builder `@nrwl/node:build` in my Angular repository (I'm using [nrwl/nx](https://github.com/nrwl/nx) monorepo pattern with NodeJS server as one of the applications).

It didn't include `tslib` in the compilation output. Setting `"externalDependencies": "none"` in the production build configuration in `angular.json` solved the issue. Credit goes to @vincastl here: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/2625

*Posting it here as it was the first post I found trying to solve this issue, perhaps I'm not alone.*

Comment: Thanks. This helped me. I searched the error and nothing helped until I added "nx" in my search and found this.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue with `jest` (+vuejs and a monorepo structure).
All the app works fine, but unit tests doesn't.

So 2 things has to be done to make them work:

1. in `tsconfig.json`:

```
    "compilerOptions": {
      "paths": {
        "tslib" : ["path/to/node_modules/tslib/tslib.d.ts"]
    }
```

2. in `jest.config.js`:

```
    moduleNameMapper: {
      'tslib': '<rootDir>/path/to/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js'
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem and it got resolved using following command!

npm install -D tslib@latest

Comment: I feel like this doesn't contribute anything over the top answer.

Answer (score 3):

**SOLUTION:**

```
>> npm install -g npm-check-updates

>> ncu -u tslib
    ...tslib  ^1.10.0  →  ^2.6.0
    [This command will update to the compatible version]

>> npm install
```

- In my case, the OP issue popped up when I upgraded my Node version from 12+ to 16+ for my Angular 9 project.
- By using the above commands, the tslib updated and the issue was fixed. :)

**Just a note:**
In case if it doesn't work, kindly undo the tslib version and run "npm install" to revert to previous state. Because, other packages that are dependent on the older version might not be compatible. This too happened in my case.

Answer (score 2):

**(2023 solution)**

As noted in the [official tslib doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslib), tslib is a **runtime** library, therefore it must *not* be installed as a `devDependencies` with the `-D` flag. Run `yarn workspace @scope/workspace add tslib` or `npm i tslib -w @scope/workspace` to fix this error.

Comment: what's `@your-org/your-work-space` here?

Comment: It's the name of a specific project in your monorepo (i.e. the `name` field in `package.json`). A monorepo has many projects (a.k.a NPM/YARN/PNPM workspaces) and each project has its own `package.json`.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue in a NX Monorepo, specifically with an express node project bundled with webpack created using `@nrwl/node`/`@nx/node`. If I just build the app for production it would run well on my local machine, but when I was trying to build into a docker container, it always returned me this error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'tslib'
Require stack:
- /app/backend/main.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/app/backend/main.js:8:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/app/backend/main.js:37:41)
    at /app/backend/main.js:51:17
    at /app/backend/main.js:63:3
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/backend/main.js:68:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/app/backend/main.js' ]
}
```

I solved it by adding `"externalDependencies": "none"` in the `project.json` file:

```
"targets": {
    "build": {
      ...
      "options": {
        ...
        "externalDependencies": "none"
      },
```

The NX documentation says:

> `externalDependencies`: Dependencies to keep external to the bundle. (`all` (default), `none`, or an array of module names)

I hope it helps anybody struggling with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm i -g tslib
```

This solved my problem. Without -g it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your project , simply run

```
npm i tslib
```

It contains all the typescript helper functions

Comment: Same as highest voted answer from 3 years prior... https://stackoverflow.com/a/53818521

Answer (score 0):

upgrading tslib version 2.00.0

in package.json it should be
"tslib": "^2.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

I had a case, where the only fix was to add this manually in `package.json` :

```
"tslib": "^2.3.1",
```

and run `npm i` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

add these lines to tsconfig.json file and inside the compilerOptions object:

```js
"compilerOptions": {
    //...rest parameters

    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "tslib" : ["path/to/node_modules/tslib/tslib.d.ts"]
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Im kind-of a newbie to JavaScript Angular React etc but i had this issue and the solution was my silly mistake of having a project folder with a space in the name
my project folder had to be renamed from :
basic-assignment-3-solution bonus
to
basic-assignment-3-solution-bonus
silly but easy to foget such a basic thing sometimes

Answer (score -1):

Add this below line in your .csproj file inside `<PropertyGroup>`:

```xml
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>True</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

Comment: How did you assume he is using .NET?

Comment: @DanielStoyanoff Most suggested solutions aren't applicable any way because the question contains a very specific problem described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52801821/3731501). I guess most posters just describe why they had this error. This may be useful for users that have a similar TS problem with a different cause, in this regard the post with C# setup doesn't look less useful as any other.