# the syntax requires an imported helper named __spreadArrays

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, spread

When I'm trying to use spreading in typescript like:

```
.reduce((unique, x) => {
    unique.some(element => element.machineName === x.machineName) ? unique : [...unique, x];
}
```

I get warning with red marking from `Visual Studio Code`:

```
the syntax requires an imported helper named __spreadArrays

typescript version: "2.3.4"
target: "es5"
```

I think in later versions this issue is fixed, but right now I can't migrate. How can I fix it?

*Note:* Project gets compiled fine and works. But red underlying in `VS Code` in annoying.

Comment: It looks like VS Code is set to target es5 instead of es6? Haven't seen that before, maybe check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953293/is-there-a-way-to-turn-on-es6-es7-syntax-support-in-vscode

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For `VS Code` the notification is based on the **tsLib** exports.
Actually nothing bad happens without doing anything, it is just lack of typing.

**Solution:** Update **tsLib** dependency to get rid of the highlighting. In my case it was version `1.9.0`. Update to `1.10.0` solved the issue.

`__spreadArrays` is added in `1.10.0` `tsLib` version:
https://github.com/microsoft/tslib/blob/1.10.0/tslib.es6.js

**Update:** Since some time passed, it is better to update version to `2.2.0` (based on last comments) or the `latest`.

Comment: What does update tslib dependency mean? Add it to package.json, to development dependencies or to devDependencies?

Comment: `npm install tslib --save` did the job for me

Answer (score 93):

In my case the problem it was `target: "es5"` in `compilerOptions` at `tsconfig.json`.

So I change it to `es6` to get it works without adding dependency.

Comment: I really think this is a more relatable answer. `tsLib` is rarely directly installed in projects.

Answer (score 47):

### Quick fix, short answer

`npm install tslib@latest --save`

---

##### Update

I got this issue again (now with tslib version 2.2.0) after updating VS Code, again updating fixed the issue.

##### Original

I had this issue with tslib version 1.14.1

`npm update tslib --save` didn't really do anything

`npm install tslib@latest --save` did the job, it updated to version 2.2.0

Comment: Had the same issue with 1.14.1. I don't know if this is an issue with that specific version (since _spreadArrays is meant to be there since 1.10.0), but installing 2.2.0 seems to be the fix

Comment: this works for me.. i had to restart my vscode..

Answer (score 30):

Assuming your tslib is installed correctly and up to date, you might still get this error in VS Code if the editor is using a different Typescript version.

(taken from [zok's answer on this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67925387/14848126))

Open Command Palette (Cmd+Shift+P on Mac. Focused file must be .ts or .tsx otherwise it won't show the option to change version)
Select "TypeScript: Select TypeScript Version..."
It shows VSCode's TS version and Workspace's (project) one, pick the workspace one

Comment: This is the only valid answer, since the question refers to a problem with vs code, supposing that the build would succeed

Answer (score 8):

This error might happen if you have in your tsconfig.json file :

```
{ 
  "importHelpers": true,
  "target": "es5"
}
```

If for any reason you can't upgrade to es6, setting importHelpers to false will make the error go away ...

Comment: One reason in my case is that the third party API I use instantiates objects without the word "new".

Answer (score 2):

from right side down
hover on curly braces beside of TypeScript and then click on version
it will give you few options, generally related to project
just select version and it will work fine

Comment:  Brilliant. The simplest solution of all. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

for yarn users: `yarn upgrade tslib@latest`

Answer (score 0):

you may need to upgrade to tslib@2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure tslint is enabled in the bottom of vscode editor options

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue with a dependency and resolved it by updating its `tsconfig.ts` with the path to the top level lastest `tslib`.

```
"importHelpers": true,
"paths": {
  "tslib": [ "../tslib/tslib.d.ts" ]
}
```