# Clone an array using spread operator with Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, state

I'm working on an Angular application and I have to update the State adding a new item to an **array**.

This is the state interface

```
export interface IState{
  //other fields of the state,
  forces: IForce[] 
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to add a new **IForce** to the field "**forces**", keeping the existent values.

This is what I'm doing inside the reducer:

```
 on(myAction, (state, {force}) => ({
    ...state,
    forces: [
      ...state.forces,
      force
    ]
  }))
```

I get this error:

```
This syntax requires an imported helper named '__spreadArray' which does not exist in 'tslib'. Consider upgrading your version of 'tslib'
```

on the line  `...state.forces`

What's the right way to achieve my goal?

Thank you guys

Comment: read the error message and follow the steps described in it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the syntax requires an imported helper named \_\_spreadArrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58329178/the-syntax-requires-an-imported-helper-named-spreadarrays)

Comment: This is a version problem try updating either your Tslint  or your TS version

Comment: I think it depends on the fact that the application targets es5. I can't update tslib, I'm looking for an alternative solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not to use concat to avoid the issue if you don't want to update.
myArr = myArr.concat(newArr);

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to install and upgrade `tslib` using your package manager, e.g. `npm install tslib; npm update tslib`.

The alternatively way is to use the array `concat` method ([Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)).

```js
on(myAction, (state, {force}) => ({
  ...state,
  forces: state.forces.concat([force])
}))
```