# Gulp 4 tasks won't finish when using @rollup/stream and es6 target in tsconfig.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gulp, rollupjs

My application relies on an internal company TS library that sees infrequent edits. I've just updated it and now one of the gulp tasks used to build it will fail. All other tasks will work in isolation or used in sequence/parallel but the one that uses the `@rollup/stream` package causes gulp to hang after declaring itself finished. This was discovered as the build automation eventually killed the build as it had paused for 2 hours waiting for the gulp tasks to complete.

I had to update our internal library as it was failing the build due to the following issue.

```sh
'rollup' errored after 1.51 s
Error: '__spreadArray' is not exported by node_modules\tslib\tslib.es6.js, imported by src\ObjectUtils.ts
```

So I updated the `tsconfig.json` file from `"target": "es5",` to `"target": "es6",` which causes the hang with rollup.

Running `gulp rollup` gives the following output

```sh
Using gulpfile path/to/gulp/file
Starting 'rollup'...
//
// Outputs all the files being rolled up here...
//
Finished 'rollup' after 1.43 s
// The gulp process then stays open instead of closing and returning me to my prompt
```

As an example I ran the task locally and later exited it myself with control+c and it reported waiting there for 10m15s

[image]

Having read all the docs and SO questions I could find I'm sure we're doing as the [async gulp tasks](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion/#returning-a-stream) docs suggest for handling streams yet it won't work. I've then tried manually closing the returned rollup stream myself using `.on('end', () => { //etc })`, wrapping things in promises and returning a promise that resolves when the stream is finished, using the callback provided to each task function, combinations of the above and yet I can't get the rollup task to properly finish and return control back to the prompt.

I've included the relevant parts of my gulpfile, the tsconfig.json and my package.json dependencies.

```js
// gulpfile.js

const gulp = require('gulp');
const gulpif = require('gulp-if');
const terser = require("gulp-terser");
const typescript = require("@rollup/plugin-typescript");
const rollup = require("@rollup/stream");
const buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

const production = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production';

function rollupTask () {
    // rollup() returns a stream, so returning this should satisfy the async tasks requirements. 
    // When the stream closes it should tell gulp the tasks has finished right?
    return rollup({
        input: "./src/main.ts",
        external: [
            "lodash",
        ],
        output: {
            format: "cjs",
            sourcemap: true
        },
        plugins: [
            typescript(),
        ],
    })
    .pipe(source("common.bundle.js"))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(gulpif(production, terser()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
};

exports.rollup = rollupTask;
```

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": false,
        "module": "es2015",
        "target": "es6",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "listFiles": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [
            "ES5",
            "Dom",
            "ScriptHost",
            "ES2015",
            "ES2016",
            "ES2017"
        ]
    }
}
```

```json
// package.json dependencies
 "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^6.1.0",
    "@rollup/stream": "^1.1.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.165",
    "del": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-if": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-terser": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-tslint": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^5.0.1",
    "merge2": "^1.4.1",
    "rollup": "^2.33.3",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.1",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0"
  },
```

If it turns out I can keep using `"target": "es5",` in the `tsconfig.json` and a fix for the `__spreadArray` issue is found then I can do that as well.

Comment: A colleague did suggest I increase our TS version after reading this related issue in Ionic https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/23090.
But it didn't make a meaningful difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was stuck between 2 different errors:

- In `tsconfig.json` setting `"target" : "ES6"` would break by never quitting the gulp task.
- In `tsconfig.json` setting to `"target" : "ES5"` would complain about a missing `__spreadArray` function in `tslib`.

Here's how I ended up fixing this:

1. Updating all the dev dependencies to latest versions.
2. Manually `tslib` using `npm i --save-dev tslib` to ensure there was a latest version available. Because I updated the TS version in step 1. which should include the latest `tslib` this is likely unnecessary...but it felt good to include it manually anyway.
3. [I found a suggestion](https://github.com/alexjoverm/typescript-library-starter/issues/310#issuecomment-643708265) to use a fork of `@rollup/plugin-typescript`  named [rollup-plugin-typescript2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-typescript2) to make it work. This itself is a strange issue as supposedly that fork only exists to add error logging in the console to tell you about any TS errors. But now the original project also outputs errors and yet doesn't work with gulp for us (or maybe just me) anymore. The fork is maintained and popular on npm so I'm not too concerned but I'd still prefer to to be on the "official" package. Obviously I changed my `gulpfile.js` to use this new package instead but it's a drop in replacement as far as API.
4. Also added the paths value to tsconfig.json to point to the installed `tslib` node module which I manually checked to make sure it had the `__spreadArray` function we needed. I found this fix in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62732422/6488602) while I was related issues for clues

Some combination of all the above fixed it. Likely 3 and 4 were the main fixes.

The following is the updated versions of my `tsconfig.json` and the relevant part of my `package.json` in case it's useful to any future reader.

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": false,
        "module": "ES2015",
        "target": "ES6",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "listFiles": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "paths": {
            "tslib": [
                "./node_modules/tslib/tslib.d.ts"
            ]
        },
        "lib": [
            "ES5",
            "Dom",
            "ScriptHost",
            "ES2015",
            "ES2016",
            "ES2017"
        ]
    }
}
```

```json
// package.json
"dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.2.5",
    "@rollup/stream": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.165",
    "del": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-if": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-terser": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-tslint": "^8.1.4",
    "gulp-typescript": "^5.0.1",
    "merge2": "^1.4.1",
    "rollup": "^2.56.3",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.30.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.1",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/"
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I think the hanging might be a bug in typescript 4.4.2 that's interacting with rollup (and perhaps, then, gulp) ... and should be fixed soon.  See https://github.com/rollup/plugins/issues/983

Comment: huh, interesting issue, thanks for the link. Unfortunately this issue was occuring before updating TS, it was previously on 4.0.5. If everything gets fixed with me using a less esoteric approach of providing paths and using a fork of a fork then I'll definitely move back to the more supported approach!